# Binary tree of binary trees copy of structure

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

in my main I have defined pointer to a binary tree and to the binary tree of binary trees:

```
tBSTNodePtr *tree;
tFunctionTREE *treeF;
```

The sctructure tBSTNodePtr looks like this:

```
typedef struct tBSTNode {
    string *Key;                                                               
    tVariable_Prom *BSTNodeCont;                                     
    struct tBSTNode * LPtr;                             
    struct tBSTNode * RPtr;                  
} tBSTNodePtr;
```

The structure `tVariable Prom` is data structure where I store my data. Then I have another structure which is tree of trees:

```
typedef struct FunctionTREE{
    string *Key;
    tBSTNodePtr *StromFunkce;
    struct FunctionTREE * LPtrF;
    struct FunctionTREE * RPtrF;
}tFunctionTREE;
```

I send both trees by their address `&tree`, `&treeF`. In the function itself they are defined as `**tree`, `**treeF`. I am using the main binary tree `**tree` and as I go trough the program I need to change the main tree to one of the trees in tree of trees in `**treeF` and I also need to store the main tree so it could be later used again with its saved values.So I defined another binary tree to store main tree:

```
tBSTNodePtr *tree_tmp;
```

Next of I have a search function which should return the pointer to a tree(it searches the tree of trees):

```
int FunctionSearchTREE(tBSTNodePtr **found,tFunctionTREE * RootPtr,string *K)
{
    if( RootPtr != NULL)
    {
    int porovnani;

    porovnani= strCmpString(RootPtr->Key,K);

    if(porovnani > 0)
    FunctionSearchTREE(found,RootPtr->RPtrF, K);
    else if(porovnani < 0)
    FunctionSearchTREE(found,RootPtr->LPtrF, K);
    else if(porovnani == 0)
    {
        (*found)=(RootPtr);
        return 0;
    }
    else return 1;

}else return 1;
}
```

It is called like this `if(FunctionSearchTREE(&odkaz2, *treeF, &Tstr) == 1) return 5;` where the `Tstr` is basically a structure which contains a string which is also a key of the tree and `odkaz2` is defined by `tBSTNodePtr*`.

Now comes the part where I am kind of lost. First of I save my main tree

```
*tree_tmp = **tree
```

(Note that the `tree_tmp` is defined in the function not the main.c thus the one `*`). Then i call the `FunctionSearchTREE` and save the address to my main tree so i can work with it:

```
**tree = odkaz2
```

When I am done working with it I switch back to my stored tree:

```
**tree = *tree_tmp;
```

However when I work with the tree I saved I get a SegFault or the values are not there.

Comment: Bumping :/ Nobody knows?

Comment: Post an SSCCE (http://sscce.org): not only you'll be more likely to get help, most of the time the simple act of writing it will make you discover the problem -- seriously. (PS what happens to the return value of your recursive calls?)

Comment: Yeah the return value wasnt there but it was functioning strangly well in other function, even if it shouldnt. Also if I understand you want me to post my whole project code to some storage and put the link here? Also the project is like 160KB in size with over 20 files(only pure code without compiling). So I think nobody would have time to read it, also it is pretty chaotic because we do it in 4 people for school project.

Comment: You seem to have missed the "short" in SSCCE. Your goal should be to construct a complete program of less than 100 or so lines of code which reproduces the problem, and then paste that in the question itself (in general, we don't really like it if questions are dependent on external sites). And purposeful bumping is not something we really do here.